# How to find coordinates $(x,y,z)$ on the helix when given a function $r(t)=\langle 2\cos(t),2\sin(t),t\rangle$?

Tags: calculus

> How to find coordinates $(x,y,z)$ on the helix when given a function $r(t)=\langle 2\cos(t),2\sin(t),t\rangle$?

So I started this problem by finding the arc length $s$ of the helix.

I integrated the magnitude of the vector from $0$ to $t$ and found that the arc length was $\sqrt 5$ multiplied by $t$. Solving for $t$ you get $s/\sqrt 5$.

I then plugged that back into the original $r(t)$, substituting the new value for $t$.

I'm lost on where to go from here. How can I convert that into coordinates of $x$, $y$, and $z$? Is it simply just the substituted version? Can you keep coordinates in terms of $s$ and $t$ or is there something else that I have to do once I have found this?

Comment: Next time please use MathJax to format equations. I did it for you this time.

Comment: It seems like your question/prompt is missing something. Perhaps you'd like coordinates of the curve *parametrized by arc length* since you went to all that effort to determine the arc length?

Comment: So in total, it asked for me to find the arc length, the asked me to find coordinates of the point on the helix for my arc length.

Answer (score 1):

As you calculated, the distance along the curve over the parameter interval $[0, t]$ is $s = t \sqrt5$. After inverting this relationship, we can substitute $t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} s$ into the coordinate functions to obtain the parametrization
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x(s) &= 2 \cos \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} s \\ 
y(s) &= 2 \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} s \\ 
z(s) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} s 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

This parametrization $\hat{r}(s) = \bigl\langle x(s), y(s), z(s) \bigr\rangle$ traces out the same helix curve as $r(t)$ but in such a way that the arc length over the interval $[0, s]$ is precisely $s$, which is equivalent to the fact that the trajectory moves at constant unit speed: $\bigl\lvert \hat{r}(s) \bigr\rvert = 1$ for all $s$.